# Waking up XBee with sensor

Tags: xbee, sleep-mode

Is it possible to wake up XBee end device with input (high) from sensor? According to documentation:

> "When the device asserts (high) Sleep_RQ, it finishes any transmit or
>   receive operations and enters a low power state."

But in my case i need inverse logic. Sensor (e.g motion sensor) setting it's control pin to high when motion detected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to invert the logic of the XBee itself. But of course you can connect an inverter (NOT gate) to the pin. This can be as simple as a transistor and two resistors, but if you want to save energy, have a look at the CMOS inverter type or special low power components.